# Custom sorting C++ list

Tags: c++

```
//
//  TemplateArray.cpp
//  C++
//
//  Created by FatJoe  on 03/12/2018.
//  Copyright © 2018 FatJoe . All rights reserved.
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

/*

 This code demonstrates representing an array and array adder using objects
 Overloading the [] operator

 */

#include<list>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class person{

public:
    int i;
    person(int j):i(j){}


};

class comparer{

public:
    bool operator()(const person& first, const person& second)const{
        cout << "operator() called" << endl;
        return true;
    };
};

int main(){

    list<person> personlist;
    list<person>::iterator itr = personlist.begin();
    personlist.insert(itr,person(1));
    personlist.insert(itr,person(2));
    personlist.insert(itr,person(3));


    for(itr=personlist.begin(); itr!=personlist.end(); itr++){
        cout << (*itr).i << "Person no." << endl;
    };

    personlist.sort(comparer());


    for(itr=personlist.begin(); itr!=personlist.end(); itr++){
        cout << (*itr).i << "Person no." << endl;
    };

    personlist.sort(comparer());


    for(itr=personlist.begin(); itr!=personlist.end(); itr++){
        cout << (*itr).i << "Person no." << endl;
    };


    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to write my own sorting criteria, i was testing out some of my own code.

In my comparer functor, i return true which means the first argument will swap with the second argument.

However, im struggling to understand why is the comparer functor called 3 times if there are 3 elements in the list, surely it would be compare(1,2) then compare(2,3)?

Comment: *"i return true which means the first argument will swap with the second argument."* - that is *not* what that means. it means the first argument is always considered "less than" the second, That completely violates [strict weak ordering](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585396/what-is-meaning-of-strict-weak-ordering-in-laymans-term), a mandatory property of the ordering you implement in a comparator submitted to a standard library sort operation. If some condition `a < b` is true, then `b < a` can *never* be, otherwise your ordering is broken (and yours is).

Comment: If the compare function returns true, the first argument if always < the second argument with comparison of some attributes. Since my list contains 2 objects, ss this < operator called on the objects provided?

Comment: There is no guarantee that the order of the arguments will have anything to do with their order in the collection. You should define a "the first argument should be ordered before the second" relationship.

Comment: Ok i understand, how many comparisons are actually called on say 3 elements in a list?

Comment: For these 2 arguments, are they adjacent elements in the list?

Comment: @WarriorJoe It can depend on how the list is ordered. The upper bound is something like 4.75

Comment: Try sorting a list of 3 elements by hand and see how many comparisons you need. There are only 6 possible permutations so you can try sorting all of them.

Comment: HERE IS A BRILLIANT QUESTION. IF IT IS SO OPTIMISED? WHY NOT USE ADJACENT ARGUMENTS ONLY?? HMMMMM....??

Comment: @nm There are 6 permutations its not = number of swaps

Comment: You want to sort *all permutations separately* and check how many *comparisons* (not swaps) when you *start with each permutation*.

Comment: Also please don't shout in the void, nobody hears you. If you want to ask a question, find the button that says "Ask a question".

Answer (score 3):

Other than being `n log n` complexity the sorting algorithm of [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) is unspecified. You'd need to look into the source code of the whichever runtime library you are using to find out how it is implemented. You should be able to step through the code with a debugger.

As your comparison function doesn't meet the specification of [`Compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) your code has undefined behaviour.

Comment: How do you even understand those reference guides, i feel like the language they use is deliberately used to confuse people. It can be written so much simpler...

Comment: @WarriorJoe It's reference material, not a user guide.The language is deliberately used to not confuse those who are familiar with the concepts and terminology. It can't be written much simpler without losing precision and detail.

Comment: I believe it is nearly impossible to debug through the STL code to get any valuable information. It is coded for maximum optimization, reusability inside the STL itself and not for public maintainability. If optimizer is turned on, all and everything implodes to nearly nothing as it should be. On most installations debug infos for STL is not installed by default. So simply tell a beginner he should use a debugger is a bit strange...

Comment: @Klaus depends on the implementation but as `std::list` is a templated class a lot of the implementation will be in the header files. If we knew which standard library he was using we could point out how it was implemented, as we don't he'll have to look for himself.

Comment: e.g. libc++'s implementation is header only: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/5fe0a6a0bc22bd48d4d90f4b45fc26098a742347/include/list#L2273 and reasonably complex but understandable if you spend a while studying it.